# ORACLE Trigger INSERT On UPDATE

Tags: oracle, triggers

All,
    I am just trying to create a trigger that will pick a whole record from TABLE EMP and insert it in TABLE EMP_ARCHIVE on an UPDATE attempt (As the name suggests, EMP_ARCHIVE Table is just a history table to store the changes made on the mail EMP Table). Both table has the same fields/columns. Following is the trigger i am trying to create. I know there is something wrong but couldn't figure out. It throws error at the '(' following the INSERT command. Any help would be appreciated. 
Forgive me if there's some fundamental error as i am a newbie to these.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Save_EMP_Changes
BEFORE UPDATE ON EMP
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO EMP_ARCHIVE
   (
      emp_id, emp_name,
      emp_age, emp_sex,
      emp_active
   )
   SELECT 
      :old.emp_id, :old.emp_name,
      :old.emp_age, :old.emp_sex,
      :old.emp_active
   FROM EMP 
   WHERE emp_id = :old.emp_id
END;
```

Comment: Your syntax error is that the Select needs parenthesis around it. a_horse_with_no_name has provided the correct answer, though. You don't require the SELECT at all.

Comment: Including the actual error message (the ORA-xxxxx error number along with the error text) will generally be helpful.  Sometimes the error will jump out at us without that but other times the error is very useful information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need to select from the table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Save_EMP_Changes
BEFORE UPDATE ON EMP
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO EMP_ARCHIVE
   (
      emp_id, emp_name,
      emp_age, emp_sex,
      emp_active
   )
   VALUES
   (  :old.emp_id, :old.emp_name,
      :old.emp_age, :old.emp_sex,
      :old.emp_active
   );
END;
```

Btw: in Oracle 11 you can completely automate this by create an FLASHBACK ARCHIVE for those tables. No trigger or any other hassle.

Comment: Prior to 11g, Workspace Manager can also be used to automate the tracking of history information.

Comment: @Justin: Yes, but it's not as easy to query information. With a flashback archive you can do a `SELECT * FROM some_table AS OF TIMESTAMP TIMESTAMP '2005-06-28 14:38:12'`

Comment: Did you include the semicolon after the INSERT? With which tool are you running this? In SQLPlus you need to terminate this with a `/` on a single line. It might be a good idea to copy & paste (as an edito the question) what you are doing in SQL*Plus in case you use it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: A quick subquestion. Trigger created using above code inserts two record in the EMP_ARCHIVE table, where i wanted only the old record to be inserted. Did you get what i am saying?

Comment: @Dine: that trigger will only insert a single row. But this will happen for each and every UPDATE you make. So if you update emp twice, you'll wind up with two rows in emp_archive.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - The flashback archive/ total recall syntax is nice for some things.  I generally prefer being able to dbms_wm.gotoDate( <<some date>> ) and then run all my existing queries/ stored procedures.  You can do the same thing with flashback archive using the DBMS_FLASHBACK package.  But Workspace Manager is free rather than an extra cost option, it's been available for quite a while, and it supports more DDL operations as the tables change over time.  Flashback archive is a much more efficient architecture though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: You sound right. But, If I update a field, lets say name from 'Mark' to 'Mike', the trigger inserts both the old record with name 'Mark' & the new record with name 'Mike' when i update it only once. I've tried changing the trigger to 'AFTER UPDATE' too. Its the same. Anyway, let me know if you find anything. I really appreciate your prompt replies.

Comment: @Dine: Is it possible you have two triggers? One defined as **AFTER** UPDATE and one defined as **BEFORE** UPDATE?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Never Mind. Its my bad. Its just two update calls. So, technically, nothing wrong with this trigger. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old question. But figured i put another idea down for anybody else that comes across this question like i just did.  In the past i've done the following when doing the same archiving process.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER Save_EMP_Changes
BEFORE UPDATE ON EMP
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO EMP_ARCHIVE
   (
      emp_id, emp_name,
      emp_age, emp_sex,
      emp_active, revision_cnt
   )
   SELECT 
      :old.emp_id, :old.emp_name,
      :old.emp_age, :old.emp_sex,
      :old.emp_active, nvl(max(revision_cnt)+1, 1)
   FROM EMP 
   WHERE emp_id = :old.emp_id
END;
```

HTH others.